# Any way to apply onclick events to a large list of li dynamically?

Tags: javascript

Ok, I have an unordered list like so:

```
<ul id=list>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
    <li> Item 4 </li>
    <li> Item 5 </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any simple way of creating onclick events for each of the individual li's?

Here's my objective... I have CSS setup like so:

```
#list li {...some styles here...}
#list li:active {...change background color and font color on click...}
```

So again, any simple way of doing this? I know I can achieve it by simply adding an onclick event to each of the individual li's, but any smart way of doing this?

(For clarification - I'm actually going to be using an 'ontouchstart' event for mobile webkit)

Comment: You might also just call a fuction and send the li's id with it. That does mean you will have to set a id for each li. But you can ofcourse do that in a for loop or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to use any third party library like jQuery, you can try something like

```
var parentNode = document.getElementById('list');
parentNode.onclick=function(e){
    e = e || event;
    var target = e.originalTarget || e.srcElement;
    if(target.nodeName == "LI"){
        alert(target.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

The code make use of javascript [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link3). It will help to reduce the number of click events registered in the page and help to increase the performance.

But I would strongly request you to look into using some matured library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Using jquery it will be as simple as

```
$("#list").delegate("li", "click", function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'your color');
    $(this).css('color', 'your color');
});
```

I would recommend the usage of [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) since it will help to reduce the number of click event registered in the page.

Comment: +1 for event delegation. That is the only sane thing to do here. It might be necessary to traverse the DOM up from the clicked element to find the `li`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If there are child elements inside the `li` that is required

Comment: No doubt jQuery is far simpler, and I probably should use it in production systems, however I'm still learning the fundamentals of JavaScript, and want to actually understand what it is that I'm doing before I have it pre-packaged for me... Thanks for showing me both options, greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Traverse them in a forloop.

and to each add ".onclick = someFunction" code.

```
<ul id='list' >
<li> Item 1 </li>
<li> Item 2 </li>
<li> Item 3 </li>
<li> Item 4 </li>
<li> Item 5 </li>
```

```
<script>
var parentNode = document.getElementById('list');
var theChilds = parentNode.getElementsByTagName("LI");

for(var i=0;i< theChilds.length; i++)
{
    var currLi = theChilds[i];
    currLi.onclick = function() { alert(this.innerHTML); }   
}
</script>
```

see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/VK5tb/

Answer (score 0):

Try a library such as [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) or [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

For example with dojo:

```
dojo.query("#list li").connect("onclick", function(){alert("Ho!");});
```

and in jquery:

```
$("#list li").click(function(e){ alert("Yo!");});
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
$("#list li").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '... your background color ...');
    $(this).css('color', '... your font color ...');
})
```